# Top-level program without executable code does not compile

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have a console app targeting net5 and the only line of code in the app is this

```
System.Console.WriteLine();
```

It works as expected, but when I remove that line I get a compilation error pointing out that an entry point is missing. This is the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs5001

My question is why there is a difference in compiler behaviour. Why does the compiler, in this case, treat a top-level program differently from a non-top-level program, where a static 'Main' method would be present?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements)

> Semantics
> If any top-level statements are present in any compilation unit of the program, the meaning is as if they were combined in the block body of a Main method of a Program class in the global namespace, as follows:

So you see, your statements were compiled inside an implicit `Main()` method. But to have this `Main()` method, you must have at least one top-level statement. This implicit statement is created only if there are top-level statement. The alternative you suggest would cause an implicit `Main()` to always be generated.

The error you see is clearly connected to this: without any line of code, no implicit `Main()` method is generated, so an *an entry point is missing* error is returned.